# Listing products to compare in views using drupal7 Dynamic properties module

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have to list out my products and allow users to compare different products.Here am using dynamic properties module.I got "Add to compare" button in every product node to compare.How to show all the products in grid using views with the "Add to compare" button using "Dynamic Properties" module?

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: Also interested in the same issue. I've been trying myself to patch the module, in order to make it appear on the views as a field, but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple contributed module https://drupal.org/project/node_compare that seems to do the job fairly well.